# Array of pointers c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a structure that has name and surname. I want to write two pointers to array (infoArr). Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char* surname;
    char* name;
}Info;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Info **infoArr = calloc(2, sizeof(Info*));  

    char* name1 = "Ian";
    char* surname1 = "Jones";
    char* name2 = "Ann";
    char* surname2 = "Stephens";

    Info *info = malloc(sizeof(Info));
    info->surname=surname1;
    info->name=name1;
    infoArr[0]=info;
    printf("infoArr[0]: %s %s\n",infoArr[0]->surname,infoArr[0]->name);

    info->surname=surname2;
    info->name=name2;
    infoArr[1]=info;
    printf("infoArr[1]: %s %s\n\n",infoArr[1]->surname,infoArr[1]->name);
    free(info);

    printf("infoArr[0]: %s %s\n",infoArr[0]->surname,infoArr[0]->name);
    printf("infoArr[1]: %s %s\n",infoArr[1]->surname,infoArr[1]->name);

    free(infoArr);

    return 0;
}
```

And as a result I receive this:

```
infoArr[0]: Jones Ian
infoArr[1]: Stephens Ann

infoArr[0]: Stephens Ann
infoArr[1]: Stephens Ann
```

What is wrong here? Why it changes first element then?

Comment: Because you are allocating only a single struct and assigning it to both pointers in the array.

Comment: `free(info);printf("infoArr[0]: %s %s\n",infoArr[0]->surname,infoArr[0]->name);` is Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```
infoArr[0] = malloc ( sizeof(Info) );
infoArr[1] = malloc ( sizeof(Info) );
```

This will create two different structs.
Now assign to each struct as

```
infoArr[0]->surname = "...";
```

Finally don't forget to free.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `infoArr[n]` are pointers, they point to *some* memory.

Next, you make `infoArr[n]`s point to the value held by `info`, via the assignments,

```
 infoArr[0]=info;
 ...
 ....
 ...
 infoArr[1]=info;
```

So, after you call `free(info);`, any access made to `infoArr[0]` or `infoArr[1]` will be invalid, as the memory location they point to has already been passed to `free()`, they don't necessarily point to any valid memory anymore. This causes causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting from `C11`, chapter §7.22.3,

> [...] The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation
>   until the deallocation. [...]

So, after the deallocation, the pointer to the  object becomes *invalid*, any access would be UB, as mentioned in chapter §6.2.4

> [...] If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
>   the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

Comment: So what to do when I want to add 100 elements to this array in loop?

Comment: @Yakimget You need to allocate memory to each `infoArr[n]`s....same way you did for `infoArr` itself, and then store values into those memory.